# use route middleware with handlebars in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

The common middle for expressjs is the Route() middleware, but now I'm dropping jade and using handlebars. Handlebars itself have it ways to define the route. Because of that I may mess up my controllers inside my app.js.

Below is my app.js, any idea how can I split the route to a new file?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render('index');
});

var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
//exported routes in ./routes/index.js
var routes = require('./routes');
//invoke routes
routes(app);
```

and routes file

```
module.exports = function(app) {
 app.post('/etc', function(req,res) {
  /* do route stuff */
});
/* other stuff goes here */
}
```

Comment: uh? is this even handlebars?